# Options Besides Using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have built a Windows Forms app that is used to generate approximately 70k SSRS reports and save them to a folder for distribution. This process takes about 8 hours to run so I tried using Parallel.ForEach() to speed things up.

I can run the app with MaxDegreeOfParallelism set to 3 as long as no other processes are accessing the report server, anything higher than that or some other process accessing the server at the same time and the report server throws an HTTP 503 error because it's overloaded. I have no control over what or when other processes can access the server so I’m concerned that setting MaxDegreeOfParallelism down to 2 may not prevent overloading the server.

I have almost no experience using the Parallel Library so I would appreciate any direction or suggestions on what I can do besides using Parallel.ForEach() to speed up this app.

Comment: Can't you just [`Retry`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry) any request that results to a 503 error? Or you are concerned that sending requests to an already overloaded server will overload it even more? In that case you could consider combining a `Retry` and a [`CircuitBreaker`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Circuit-Breaker) mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

First thing in your analysis is, is your task processor intensive or I/O intensive, this will help you decide whether to use Parallel.ForEach() for processor intensive processing or something like Task.WhenAll for I/O intensive processing.

According to your question, I believe this is more a I/O intensive process but is hard to say without being able to see your code.

Is time in each process being spent on database queries, on file reads/writes or in actual processor operations? These are the key questions you need to answer to find the best solution.

Also you can consider new language tools like async streams, or parallel foreach async

You can find some great examples here :

https://scatteredcode.net/parallel-foreach-async-in-c/